# Corsair Sable Mouse increases boot time by 70 seconds

Tags: boot, dual-boot, usb, mouse, usbhid

Just bought a Corsair Sabre RGB mouse. When plugged in on boot, it greatly increases the boot time. Here's dmesg:

```
$ dmesg

[   26.202654] usbhid 3-4:1.2: can't add hid device: -110
[   26.202725] usbhid: probe of 3-4:1.2 failed with error -110
[   61.199211] usbhid 3-4:1.3: can't add hid device: -110
[   61.199290] usbhid: probe of 3-4:1.3 failed with error -110
[   61.199356] usbcore: registered new interface driver usbhid
[   61.199359] usbhid: USB HID core driver
[   61.200915] input: Corsair Corsair Gaming Sabre PRO RGB Mouse as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-4/3-4:1.0/0003:1B1C:1B2F.0001/input/input1
[   61.201082] hid-generic 0003:1B1C:1B2F.0001: input,hidraw0: USB HID v1.11 Mouse [Corsair Corsair Gaming Sabre PRO RGB Mouse] on usb-0000:00:14.0-4/input0
[   71.198216] hid-generic 0003:1B1C:1B2F.0002: usb_submit_urb(ctrl) failed: -1
[   71.198331] hid-generic 0003:1B1C:1B2F.0002: timeout initializing reports
[   71.198503] input: Corsair Corsair Gaming Sabre PRO RGB Mouse as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-4/3-4:1.1/0003:1B1C:1B2F.0002/input/input2
[   71.254530] hid-generic 0003:1B1C:1B2F.0002: input,hidraw1: USB HID v1.11 Mouse [Corsair Corsair Gaming Sabre PRO RGB Mouse] on usb-0000:00:14.0-4/input1
[   71.255347] hid-generic 0003:1B1C:1C0B.0003: hiddev0,hidraw2: USB HID v1.11 Device [                                                ] on usb-0000:00:14.0-12/input0
```

After boot, the mouse works. Is there any way I can fix this? Corsair is notorious for not releasing Linux drivers. I tried the ckb github project but that did me no good. Should I return this mouse?

Thanks in advanced folks:

llldino

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Added the following line to my kernal cmdline:

```
usbhid.quirks=0x1B1C:0x1B2F:0x20000408
```

llldino