# Why is my mouse randomly recognized ? Corsair Harpoon

Tags: usb, mouse

I use a Corsair Harpoon mouse since one year.
She is recognized since I start my computer, until Ubuntu loads.
There, **randomly**, the mouse won't be recognized.

I just have to unplug/replug and it's fine. When it's done, the mouse will works until shutdown.

It happens same way with every usb ports, 3.0 or not.
It never happens on Windows 10.

I was on Ubuntu 18.04 with kernel 4.15. So i upgraded for 18.10 with kernel 4.18. Now i'm on 19.10 with kernel 5.3. 
And i have to say that's better, but still randomly not recognized.

ckb github project do not change anything.

**dmesg if my mouse is recognized :**

```
hid-generic 0003:1B1C:1B3C.0004: input,hidraw3: USB HID v1.11 Mouse [Corsair Corsair Gaming HARPOON RGB Mouse] on usb-0000:00:14.0-13/input0
```

And this one could be a clue ?

```
usbhid 3-13:1.2: couldn't find an input interrupt endpoint
```

**dmesg if my mouse is not recognized :**

```
[    6.545937] usb 3-9: unable to read config index 0 descriptor/all
[    6.545939] usb 3-9: can't read configurations, error -110
[    6.673887] usb 3-9: new full-speed USB device number 6 using xhci_hcd
[   11.921965] usb 3-9: unable to read config index 0 descriptor/all
[   11.921967] usb 3-9: can't read configurations, error -110
[   11.921983] usb usb3-port9: attempt power cycle
[   12.573887] usb 3-9: new full-speed USB device number 7 using xhci_hcd
[   17.809965] usb 3-9: unable to read config index 0 descriptor/all
[   17.809967] usb 3-9: can't read configurations, error -110
[   17.937887] usb 3-9: new full-speed USB device number 8 using xhci_hcd
[   23.185913] usb 3-9: unable to read config index 0 descriptor/all
[   23.185925] usb 3-9: can't read configurations, error -110
[   23.185940] usb usb3-port9: unable to enumerate USB device
```

I saw a tips i didn't try, because i don't understand it, [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/805039/corsair-sable-mouse-increases-boot-time-by-70-seconds)

And if that's not a big problem because replug the mouse is a solution, i can't understand why this bug is a random bug...

Any idea ?

Comment: My mouse works fine on the same computer with the same USB port when it's started on Windows 10. I will try again to change usb ports, but like it's a random problem i won't have a clear and immediate effect :)

Comment: @SchtroumpfàLunettes open a terminal (using **Ctrl** + **Alt** + **T** shortcut), and use `sudo cat /dev/input/mice`. Now, just use your mouse (move it, right/left click) -> if you see some non ASCII character (there is also some `(` and `8` characters) printed on your terminal, so the mouse is recognized

Comment: ��(�(��(��(�(��(��(��(��8�� : seems recognized. So why sometimes not ?

Comment: Same problem with 20.04. Random bug. How is it possible to have a really random bug ?